# convert snippet to wpf format combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, combobox

I developed a web app and it contains a portion where i populate combobox using an xml file. Now I am required to develop WPF app that does the same thing using the same xml file.

My question is this: Can I reuse the code snippet as shown with some modifications? How do I modify it? I understand I cannot use .DataTextField .DataSource and .DataBind since I cannot use the System.Web namespaces

```
public void PopulateDDLFromXMLFile()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("C:\abc.xml");


    DataView dv = ds.Tables["builder"].DefaultView;
    DataView dw = ds.Tables["manager"].DefaultView;

    dv.Sort = "value";

    comboBox1.DataTextField = "value";
    comboBox2.DataTextField = "value";
    comboBox1.DataSource = dv;
    comboBox1.DataBind();
    comboBox2.DataSource = dw;
    comboBox2.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Where does System.Web come into this?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result or error? I don't see any problem with this code working on WPF.

Comment: @shiv kumar i tried. i get this error: 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That's right, I assumed you know that since you mentioned it in your question. So what is the question then? You obviously can't reuse the same exact code. Please re-state the question and make it clear what it is you're looking to do

Comment: @shiv Kumar how do i modify it?

Comment: You cannot use the same snippet for WPF because everything is different in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure but i think it'd have to be something going in that direction:

```
    public void PopulateDDLFromXMLFile()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("C:\abc.xml");


        DataView dv = ds.Tables["builder"].DefaultView;
        DataView dw = ds.Tables["manager"].DefaultView;

        dv.Sort = "value";

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = dv; //Sets the collection of items from which to populate
        comboBox2.ItemsSource = dw;

        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "value"; //Sets the path within an item to use for display
        comboBox2.DisplayMemberPath = "value";
    }
```